# Google Sheet scripts to 'only allow Paste as Value' or 'lock Conditional Formatting rules'

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Few of us share a Google Sheet file and work on it concurrently. The cells in the Google Sheet worksheet have built-in conditional formatting logic to help keep our workflows efficient. However, often, when pasting from another online source, many of us end up overwriting the cells' rules. We're aware of Cmd+Shift+V, but I'm curious if there is a script that can preserve Conditional Formatting rules against inadvertent overwrites or a way to Lock conditional formatting as a security layer in Google Sheets.